# Nestjs swagger authorizations with JWT Token returning unauthorised even after passing token

Tags: jwt, swagger, authorization, nestjs, documentation

I am using JWT strategy for authorization. I'm using the token to validate the user in all controllers. And I've successfully managed to get the desired response in postman after setting the token in Auth Bearer Token.
But After Setting the token in swagger  as given bellow
[image]

I'm getting an Unauthorized response. The reason must be, that somehow inside the swagger my controllers are not getting access to the token.
Following is the code for swagger documentation.

```
export function createDocument(app:INestApplication): OpenAPIObject{
const builder = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle(SWAGGER_CONFIG.title)
    .setVersion(SWAGGER_CONFIG.version)
    .addBearerAuth({
        type:"http",
        scheme:'bearer',
        bearerFormat:'JWT',
    
        } ,'access-token')
                        
const options = builder.build();
return SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
```

}

Following is a example of a controller

```
@ApiTags("Users")
@Controller('users')
export class UserController {
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    @Get('me')
    @ApiOkResponse({ description:"Successfully returned response"})
    @ApiForbiddenResponse({ description: "Forbidden" })
    async profile(@Req() request, @Res() response){
    some code}
```

following is a example of one of the swagger route
[image]

[image]

please let me know where am I getting it wrong
any help would a appreciated

Comment: use `@ApiBearerAuth('access-token')` on your controller class

Comment: My bad, how did I missed it. Thank you so much @SopheakSek

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not send `jwt` token, it depends what backend framework you are using, I had this experience in `NestJS` where I put first `@UseGuards` than `@Post`, but I should

```
@UseGuards()
@Post()
    
decorators are calling from bottom to top
@Decorator3
@Decorator2
@Decorator1
function() {
  //logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , I could solve this looking into:

https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/98

and

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/11-swagger/src/cats/cats.controller.ts

and I tried to figure out what was the thing that I didn't add.
In my case I forgot to add the @ApiBearerAuth() decorator on my protected controller.